# Convert Some unknown location format to Decimal format

Tags: convert, latitude-longitude, point-of-interest

I have seen one Website, which contains the coordinate and other information. I found that coordinates is in a different format, I can't convert to decimal format.

The Website is : [Check here Information](http://www.gipfelderschweiz.ch/gipfel/liste.php)

In this site, the last column contains the coordinates, which need to convert into decimal format.

After click on the Mountain name, I can get the decimal format, but I don't want to click 5000 times.

For Example.

Curent format is :

> 568'830 / 89'080

TO

> 45.95258N   7.03665O

I want to convert this coordinate format to decimal geolocation format anyhow. It should be online or offline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The coordinates <strike>seem to be</strike> are in "[Swiss grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_coordinate_system)" coordinate System. [EPSG:21781](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/21781/)

[image]

-> Copy paste the table to a Text file (it will be tab-separated CSV), remove the `'` between the numbers. Replace the `/` between the coordinates with a tab (`\t`) and import into QGIS with the corresponding fields for X and Y and EPSG:21781 as CRS. From here you can convert the data to any CRS you wish.

---

**How did I find out:**

1. Which area are the coordinates supposed to cover? (=> Switzerland)
2. Search Google for official or common coordinate systems used in that region (here: [q=koordinatensystem+schweiz"](https://www.google.de/search?q=koordinatensystem%20schweiz))
3. Trial and Error (This time the first try was a hit!)

Comment: @Sagar Vaghela : once you found the system and created the point cloud like Rovo did, a simple transformation (Save as, in QGIS) from EPSG:21781 to EPSG:4326 (lat/long WGS84 coordinate system) should give you the data in the right coordinate system you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the understanding. I also found one website which useful to convert this format. [Conversion of Swiss coordinate](http://www.giangrandi.ch/soft/swissgrid/swissgrid.shtml)